# Can I change only one ticket of a multiple ticket purchase (Ryanair)?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, ryanair

I've booked roundtrip tickets on Ryanair from point A to point B, for three people.

Is it possible to change return date for only one of them? Or do they require me to change the three of them?

Comment: What do you mean by "change"? Have you bought flexible tickets? For Ryanair that is highly unlikely and a fairly new option? Your best bet will be to get a new return ticket for the one person and ask for a refund of the fees for the non-used ticket (but make sure not to cancel the tickets for the other two in the process).

Answer (score 8):

Ryan air will create a new reference number free of charge for the person who needs to change their flights.  I've just done this and it was not a problem.  Did it using their on-line chat

Comment: Thank you, and welcome to TSE; this is very useful. Might you expand it to include the link to the [Ryanair](https://www.ryanair.com/us/en/useful-info/help-centre/faq-overview/contact-us/Ryanair-live-chat-service)? If it's the link in this comment, I can show you how or do it for you.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how the tickets were bought:

- If there was a special offer ('buy two, get one free', or so), then you obviously cannot change one of them.
- If they are independent (easily visible by the booking code - three different booking codes = independent), the airline wouldn't even now that you have multiple tickets, and it would be no problem to change one without changing the others (always assuming they *can* be changed *at all*)
- If the tickets are on *one* booking code, it depends on the airline and its willingness. I would expect most airlines to do that without any problems (after all, they get a fee for the change), but Ryanair is not *most* airlines. So the only way to know is to call them and try.

Comment: I think you are still over-estimating costumer service of Ryanair.